# Tracking the number of users in a Java application

Tags: java, url

So I have a Java application and I'm wanting to count the number of users who are using the application at any given time. The way I've opted to do this is to host a 777 txt file and add a character to the file whenever a user opens the app, count the characters in order to determine how many users are 'online', and then remove a character when the application is closed.

So far I haven't been able to write to the txt file effectively, and my doubts about the effectiveness of this method are being confirmed. It seems really clumsy. Does anyone have any better ideas about how to achieve this goal?

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using to write to the txt file:

```
URL url;
URLConnection urlConn;
try {
  url = new URL("http://blalalah.com/blah.txt");
  urlConn = url.openConnection(); 
  urlConn.setDoInput(true); 
  urlConn.setDoOutput(true); 
  urlConn.setUseCaches(false); 
  urlConn.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
  dos.writeBytes("#");
  dos.flush();
  dos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Do you use database in your app? Do you want to store that data in txt file? Maybe you can use only static field?

Comment: The amount of data stored online is minimal so I've not felt the need for a database yet.

Comment: How do you expect your url (*.txt) to process your request? Usually you need a server side script to do that

Comment: I think if all information store online, you only need a static counter

Comment: How would I implement a static counter? I could use a PHP script to process the request I guess, such as here: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/39429-java-writing-to-online-txt-file/ but that seems like overkill.